# Search strings in a string and make array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string

I have this script. Cause I want to scrap from a website my agenda I need to start
with de basics. So I need to know how I can find strings. I already have something
like it. I works also nothing wrong. But cause an agenda has 30/31 days so
i don't want to scrap one day.

Below you will see my script and the results are just : Jamal Entingh

I like to get all the names into an array.

My agenda will have variables in a array like my shift on the day L2040 and the Time 12:00 - 18:45 and other stuff like location.

I was thinking about an for loop or while loop to set this straight.

So short again all between naam and end must be set in an array.

```
NSString *Field = @"naamJamal EntinghendnaamUlrich EsajasendnaamSerginho Herbertend";


NSString *Names = [[[[Field componentsSeparatedByString:@"naam"]objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"end"]objectAtIndex:0];

txtveld.text = Names;
```

I have this question for an array scrapt from a website.

I dont going to put the full html but an example

```
<ul class="rsevent">

<li class="rsevent"><a href="url 1"><strong>Partys going on</strong></a> <small>(5 augustus 2012)</small><small><p>The party is going on people be there.</p>
</small></li>

<li class="rsevent"><a href="url 2"><strong>Borgoe Party: vrijdag 31 augustus 2012</strong></a> <small>(31 augustus 2012)</small><small><p>Off Corso in Rotterdam is going down borgoe party</p>
</small></li>

<li class="rsevent"><a href="url 3"><strong>Dutch Kizomba Festival</strong></a> <small>(7 september 2012)</small><small><p>Dutch Kizomba Festival. The place where you need to be</p>
</small></li>

</ul>
```

This is the part i scrapt from a website for the events.

```
NSString *AanvraagUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.thewebsite.org/category/events/"];

NSString *CodeerUrl = [AanvraagUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *Url = [NSURL URLWithString:CodeerUrl];

NSString *Scrapper = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:Url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];

NSString *Scrapdeel = [[[[Scrapper componentsSeparatedByString:@"<div class=\"agenda\">"]objectAtIndex:1]componentsSeparatedByString:@"div>"]objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *Events = [[[[Scrapdeel componentsSeparatedByString:@"<ul class=\"rsevent\">"]objectAtIndex:1]componentsSeparatedByString:@"</ul>"]objectAtIndex:0];
```

This is wat i have.I want all the data into array's but how is my question. Here some like this

```
NSArray *EventDate
NSArray *EventSubject
NSArray *EventInfo
```

I tried different kinda loops with CompenentsSeperatedByString again but it gives me 1 result repeated. Some buddy help me out.

Comment: And which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Having two different separators, 'naam' and 'end', makes it a bit more difficult to handle but something like this should give you a start:

```
NSString *field = @"naamJamal EntinghendnaamUlrich EsajasendnaamSerginho Herbertend";
NSArray *split = [field componentsSeparatedByString:@"end"];
for (NSString *s in split) {
    if ([s length] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", [s substringFromIndex:[@"naam" length]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: OW ja thnxx that works. I just bought a book Objective-C to learn. Maybe something a harder question will come cause this looks easy.